# VkApi, загрузка файла на сервер вк

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, curl

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь решить эту проблему уже третий день, но ничего не выходит.

Суть в том, что мне по url картинке надо сначала сохранить её к себе в файле(**только cURL**), а потом как-то передать её на сервер вк, который мне возвращает один метод. Всё это только cURL.

Вот таким кодом я **пыталась** загружать изображение на свой сервер:

```
$url = $query["response"]["upload_url"];

$file2 = "https://pp.userapi.com/c834204/v834204071/2e431/hRxE5SHqV2s.jpg";


$ch = curl_init($file2);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);
 $fp = fopen('../vk_post/allow_url_fopen/image.jpg', 'wb');
 fclose($fp);
```

Но ничего в результате. Так и не додумалась как можно загрузить файл с фото на сервер вк.

Буду чрезвычайно благодарна, если вы покажете как исполнить хоть один шаг - загрузку на мой сервер или на сервер вк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так, например. Сначала создаем  у себя копию картинки, затем грузим, затем unlink

```
copy($file,'./tempimg.jpg');
$lala = "./tempimg.jpg";
$cfile = curl_file_create($lala,'image/jpeg','test_name.jpg');
$postparam = array("file1"=>$cfile);

$ch = curl_init($server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postparam);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
unlink('./tempimg.jpg');
```